# .delegate self unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I've a `TableViewController` in which I'm saving the selected cells in an `NSMUtableArray`. After selecting these cells user clicks on a confirm button and in this button action I'm trying to pass that `NSMUtableArray` so that I can display it in another `viewController` `tableView`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SelectedDXDelegate;

@interface AddDXTableViewController : UITableViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *favDXArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DX *AddEditDX;

@property (weak) id<SelectedDXDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)confirmPressed:(id)sender;

@end

@protocol SelectedDXDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)getSelectedDX:(NSMutableArray *)DXselected;
@end
```

So when confirm button is pressed

```
- (IBAction)confirmPressed:(id)sender {

    [self.delegate getSelectedDX:selectedDX];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

it gets me to the

```
-(void)getSelectedDX:(NSMutableArray *)DXselected
{
    myDXSelected = DXselected;
}
```

But it crashes the app here at reloadData in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.DXTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: One more thing did you write/define the delegate method in your class, As it is required type, so you must write it in your  controller. Are you doing that ??

Comment: I saw your try to instantiate, it is not as I suggested earlier, did you type casted ?? See here , after the equal sign I wrote to type cast. 

Like this : AddDXTableViewController * addDXTVC = (AddDXTableViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DXViewController"];

Comment: yes I did it as you said and I've also tried it with `AddDXTableViewController * addDXTVC = (AddDXTableViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DXViewController"];` but didn't work.

Comment: Ok, One more thing, did you assign the "AddDXTableViewController" in the story board in "identity Inspector" under class tag ?? You might not make the UIViewController to AddDXTableViewController there, so while fetching it returns you UIViewController from the story board. Let me know

Comment: I gave `DXViewController` a Storyboard ID named `DXViewController`. But I haven't gave any Storyboard ID to `AddDXTableViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up which view controller should be the delegate and which is the delegator.  Also, you are just allocating a new instance of the `AddDXTableViewController` and assigning this as the delegate. This won't work; you need to have the existing instance of your view controller set as the delegate.

From what I can tell from your question, it is actually an instance of `DXViewController` that is to be the delegate of `AddDXTableViewController`

Presumably in `DXViewController` you have some code something like:

```
AddDXViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddDXViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

What you need to do is set your delegate at this point:

```
AddDXViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddDXViewController"];
newViewController.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

Having said all of that, since you are using a storyboard, a delegate is probably an unnecessarily complicated way of achieving your requirement; You can use a segue to move between the first and second view controller and an unwind segue to return back to the first.  You can then implement `prepareForSegue` in the second view controller and use that to provide the array back to the first view controller

Comment: I want to get `NSMutableArray` created in `AddDXTableViewController` in `DXViewController`. However in `DXViewController` there is a bar button (UIButton) which I've ctrl+drag pushed the `AddDXTableViewController` So there is no code for Push.

Comment: By applying the method you suggested I'm getting the same error in `-(void)getSelectedDX:(NSMutableArray *)DXselected` where I've `myDXSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:DXselected];`

Comment: If you have just ctrl_dragged then you have a segue, so you need to use code in `prepareForSegue` in order to access the destination view controller and set the delegate

Comment: I've changed it to the way you showed me and it's working fine now.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `UIViewController` added in storyboard to `AddDXTableViewController` type in the identity inspector tab in story board.

See here the image 
[image]

Here you can see the class type is ViewController, click on the dropdown and select the type to `AddDXTableViewController`

then type cast the viewController to `AddDXTableViewController`. As per my guess the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` returns `UIViewController` which does not have delegate may cause the crash

```
AddDXTableViewController *addDXTVC = (AddDXTableViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DXViewController"];
addDXTVC.delegate = self;
```

Let me know If it works

Comment: see my updated question. The answer below seems to get me to the delegate call but I'm getting the same error in `-(void)getSelectedDX:(NSMutableArray *)DXselected` where I've `myDXSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:DXselected];`

Comment: You did not checked the checkmark to use the Storyboard Id. Check mark that one and assign the same story board id which you have taken to access in your Controller